Disable list view items independently in Flutter
I am new to Flutter and I am building a list view with multiple tile which each tile has a button to mark the list item as a favourite. I am using bloc pattern to do the server call and updating the button look and feel by changing colour if it's successfully marked as a favourite.
But when the button colours updating it affects all the items in list view. I've done like below,
Button Class Implementation
class FavoriteButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool isFavorite;
  final PackageEntity package;

  const FavoriteButton({
    super.key,
    required this.isFavorite,
    required this.package,
  });

  @override
  State<FavoriteButton> createState() => _FavoriteButtonState();
}

class _FavoriteButtonState extends State<FavoriteButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 30,
      height: 30,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
        color: widget.isFavorite
            ? AppColors.white.withOpacity(0.9)
            : AppColors.purple.withOpacity(0.9),
      ),
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Image.asset(
          widget.isFavorite
              ? 'assets/images/icon/heart_filled.png'
              : 'assets/images/icon/heart_outlined.png',
          width: 20,
          height: 20,
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          BlocProvider.of<RemotePackageFavoriteBloc>(context).add(
            SetPackagesFavorite(PackageFavoriteRequest(
              widget.package,
              currentUser,
              !widget.package.isFavourite,
            )),
          );
        },
        iconSize: 48,
        splashRadius: 24,
        tooltip: 'Like',
      ),
    );
  }
}

Parent Class implementation
Positioned(top: 5, left: 165,
    child: BlocBuilder<RemotePackageFavoriteBloc,RemotePackageFavoriteState>(
        builder: (BuildContext context, RemotePackageFavoriteState favoriteState) {
            if (favoriteState is RemotePackageFavoriteInitial) {
                return FavoriteButton(isFavorite: package.isFavourite,package: package);
            }
            
            if (favoriteState is RemotePackageFavoriteLoading) {
                return const Center(child:CupertinoActivityIndicator());
            }

            if (favoriteState is RemotePackageFavoriteError) {
                return const Center(child:Text('Something went wrong!'));
            }

            if (favoriteState is RemotePackageFavoriteDone) {
                int index = _fetchedPackages.indexWhere((pkg) => pkg.id == package.id);
                if (index != -1) {
                    _fetchedPackages[index] = PackageModel.fromEntity(_fetchedPackages[index].copyWith(isFavourite:!_fetchedPackages[index].isFavourite));
                }
                return FavoriteButton(isFavorite: _fetchedPackages[index].isFavourite, package: package);
                }
                return const SizedBox.shrink();
           },
     ),
)

In here I want to do 2 things.

While the server call is happening, need to disable the button till I get a success/error response.
Change the colours of the container and change the icon independently.

I tried to disable button by adding a bool disableButton = false in button class and then make it true before BlocProvider.of call on button pressed. But it didn't disable the button as expected and won't be able to click after 1st time. How can I fix this?
